# Hide sidebar on 1 page glitches homepage content

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

I would like to hide the sidebar on just 1 specific page and allow the content to take the full 100%. I am using liquid. I have done this:

```
{% if page.handle != 'lorem' %}
<main-sidebar class="sidebar {% if page.handle == 'lorem' %} blockCSS {% endif %}">
```

It works.

But then you check the homepage and normally all the sections are wrapped within the content-holder div but for some reason after adding that piece of code after 3 sections they are outside of that div. I have not even changed that div at all.

How do I ensure that all sections that come after the first 3 that they are also in the content-holder?

Comment: I think anyone would need the code of the theme to debug this